# Flot Chart Y axis Position

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, flot

I am using Flot for graphing. I put this chart in a div, and when I resize the div, however, i found that the labels of YAxis don't move accordingly, and they just stay at the inital positions. labels for XAxis are ok. I am wondering how could this happen? do I need to set up additional parameters? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the [resize](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/resize.html) plugin:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flot.resize.js"></script> 

//do plotting as normal
```

If you are already using the resize plugin, something more fundamental is probably wrong...  It might be useful to see more code in that case.